# How to delete the selected row in data grid? Using vb.net and ms access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

here`s my code. The function of this is to insert the selected row to another table and delete it from the current table. My code is working but if I select the last or middle row in the datagrid it is selecting the 1st data on the row.

```
'transferring data from acess to textbox
            Dim i As Integer
            i = dgMembers.CurrentRow.Index
            currentid = dgMembers.Item(0, i).Value.ToString()

            txtMemberDate.Text = dgMembers.Item(0, i).Value.ToString()
            txtMemberIDNo.Text = dgMembers.Item(1, i).Value.ToString()
            txtMemberFirstName.Text = dgMembers.Item(2, i).Value.ToString()
            txtMemberLastName.Text = dgMembers.Item(3, i).Value.ToString()
            txtMemberMobileNo.Text = dgMembers.Item(4, i).Value.ToString()
            cbMemberGender.Text = dgMembers.Item(5, i).Value.ToString()
            dtpMember.Text = dgMembers.Item(6, i).Value.ToString()
            txtMemberPassword.Text = dgMembers.Item(7, i).Value.ToString()
            txtMemberAddress.Text = dgMembers.Item(8, i).Value.ToString()
            'insert data to another table
            ds2 = New DataSet
            adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("insert into [Deleted_MemberAccounts] ([Date_Registered], 
            [ID_No] , [FirstName], [LastName], [Mobile_No], [Gender], [Birthday], 
            [Password], [Address]) VALUES " & "('" & txtMemberDate.Text & "','" &
            txtMemberIDNo.Text & "','" & txtMemberFirstName.Text & "','" &
            txtMemberLastName.Text & "','" & txtMemberMobileNo.Text & "','" &
            cbMemberGender.Text & "','" & dtpMember.Text &
            "','" & txtMemberPassword.Text & "','" & txtMemberAddress.Text & "')", conn)
            adapter.Fill(ds2, "Deleted_MemberAccounts")
            txtMemberIDNo.Text = ""
            txtMemberFirstName.Text = ""
            txtMemberLastName.Text = ""
            txtMemberMobileNo.Text = ""
            cbMemberGender.Text = Nothing
            dtpMember.Text = Nothing
            txtMemberPassword.Text = ""
            txtMemberCPassword.Text = ""
            txtMemberAddress.Text = ""
            GetMembersRecord()
            'delete data from current table
            Dim a As Integer
            a = dgMembers.CurrentRow.Index
            currentid = dgMembers.Item(0, a).Value.ToString()
            ds = New DataSet
            adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("delete from [FASA_MembersAccount] where ID_No = " & currentid, conn)
            adapter.Fill(ds, "FASA_MembersAccount")
            GetMembersRecord()
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Apologies. Didn't fully understand question.  Ignore comment.

Comment: What are all those text boxes doing? What not get the values directly from the DataGridView?

Comment: NEVER store passwords as plain text.

Comment: Is this WinForms?

Comment: Can you post the complete code? Also post the code where you populate the DataGridView. The data type of the .DataSource is important to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the SelectedRows collection.

```
If grid.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
  For Each row As DataGridViewRow In grid.SelectedRows
    '--- deletion code
  Next
End if
```

Comment: Hello it`s not working :-( do you have a code of soft delete?

Comment: .SelectedRow is not a member of DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of the DataAdapter is expecting the text of a SelectCommand. Your code makes no sense. You are trying to fill a DataSet with an Insert command.

You seem to have some confusion over what the Primary Key field is.
`currentid = dgMembers.Item(0, i).Value.ToString()` would indicate the first column is the PK but that is a date according to `txtMemberDate.Text = dgMembers.Item(0, i).Value.ToString()`. I will make an assumption that dgMembers.Item(1) is the correct column for the PK. You will have to correct my code if it is another column.

Keep your database objects local so you can ensure that they are closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks do this for you even it there is an error.

Always use parameters to avoid Sql injection. I had to guess at the data types and sizes of the fields. Check you database for the actual types and sizes. The data types should match the conversion of the values. In OleDb (Access) the names of the parameters don't matter. The order that they are added to the parameters collection must match the order that they appear in the sql command.

Not only should passwords NEVER be stored as plain text but I see not point in retrieving them, displaying them in a grid and storing them in the deleted table. Very bad for security.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim i = dgMembers.CurrentRow.Index
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("Insert Into [Deleted_MemberAccounts] ([Date_Registered], 
        [ID_No] , [FirstName], [LastName], [Mobile_No], [Gender], [Birthday], 
        [Password], [Address]) VALUES (@MemberDate,@MemberID,@FName,@LName,@MobileNo,@Gender, @Birthday, @Password,@Address", conn)
            With cmd.Parameters
                .Add("@MemberDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = CDate(dgMembers.Item(0, i).Value)
                .Add("@MemberID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(dgMembers.Item(1, i).Value)
                .Add("@FName", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = dgMembers.Item(2, i).Value.ToString()
                .Add("@LName", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = dgMembers.Item(3, i).Value.ToString()
                .Add("@MobileNo", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = dgMembers.Item(4, i).Value.ToString()
                .Add("@Gender", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = dgMembers.Item(5, i).Value.ToString()
                .Add("@Birthday", OleDbType.Date).Value = CDate(dgMembers.Item(6, i).Value)
                .Add("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = dgMembers.Item(7, i).Value.ToString()
                .Add("@Address", OleDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = dgMembers.Item(8, i).Value.ToString()
            End With
            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using 'Disposes the first command
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("Delete From [FASA_MembersAccount] where ID_No = @ID", conn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(dgMembers.Item(1, i).Value)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using 'Disposes the second command
    End Using 'Closes and Disposes the connection
    dgMembers.Rows.Remove(dgMembers.CurrentRow)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello sorry for my bad. i`m just a newbie. Thanks for your help and tips. i already solved the problem with my code. i figure out that i declared  2 integer which is the "i" and "a" that makes confuse the adapter. Btw what is the difference between OLeDbADatadapter and OlebdCommand?

Comment: A command is a simpler object. An adapter is capable of updating the database if the original Select is for a single table. It needs to be set up with the appropriate Update, Insert and Delete commands. This can be done with a CommandBuilder.  If you want to roll your own use the command. If you want some degree of automation use the DataAdapter to .Fill and then later you can use it to Update.

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone thanks for your response i already figure out the problem with my code i declared 2 integer which is the "i" and "a" that makes confuse the adapter. Here`s my new code

```
  Dim i As Integer
            i = dgMembers.CurrentRow.Index
            currentid = dgMembers.Item(0, i).Value.ToString()

            'insert data to another table
            ds2 = New DataSet

            adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("insert into [Deleted_MemberAccounts] ([Date_Registered], 
                [ID_No] , [FirstName], [LastName], [Mobile_No], [Gender], [Birthday], 
                [Password], [Address]) VALUES " & "('" & dgMembers.Item(0, i).Value.ToString() & "','" &
                dgMembers.Item(1, i).Value.ToString() & "','" & dgMembers.Item(2, i).Value.ToString() & "','" &
                dgMembers.Item(3, i).Value.ToString() & "','" & dgMembers.Item(4, i).Value.ToString() & "','" &
                dgMembers.Item(5, i).Value.ToString() & "','" & dgMembers.Item(6, i).Value.ToString() &
                "','" & dgMembers.Item(7, i).Value.ToString() & "','" & dgMembers.Item(8, i).Value.ToString() & "')", conn)
            adapter.Fill(ds2, "Deleted_MemberAccounts")
            GetMembersRecord()
            GetDeletedMembersRecord()
            'delete data from current table

            currentid = dgMembers.Item(1, i).Value.ToString()
            ds = New DataSet
            adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("delete from [FASA_MembersAccount] where ID_No = " & currentid, conn)
            adapter.Fill(ds, "FASA_MembersAccount")
            GetMembersRecord()
            GetDeletedMembersRecord()
```